# how can i write a text on the image and save it

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, ios7, uiimage

im trying to first upload an image then write a text on it and after that save both items as one image. 
im new in objective c so my code might be not the best way to get to my goal any help and suggestion wil help me.
thank you all
this is my code :

some how this editor is not allowing me to put my method declaration on
    enter code here

```
UIImage *image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

NSData *data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);

NSString *mijnImage =@"mijnImage.png";

NSArray *route = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentationDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

NSString *imageRoute = [route objectAtIndex:0];

NSString *routeNaarDeBestaand = [imageRoute stringByAppendingPathComponent:mijnImage];

[data writeToFile:routeNaarDeBestaand atomically:YES];

[[self imageView]setImage:image];

[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:Nil];

self.imageView.image = [self drawText:@"Test String" inImage:image atPoint:CGPointMake(10, 20)];
```

this is another methode declaration same problem the editor is not allowing me to put it on

```
UIFont *font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:100];

UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.frame.size);

[originalImage drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,self.view.frame.size.width,self.view.frame.size.height)];

CGRect rect = CGRectMake(point.x, point.y,lblText.frame.size.width, lblText.frame.size.height);

rect.size = [text sizeWithAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:150.0f]}];

NSMutableDictionary *attributes = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

[attributes setObject:font forKey:NSFontAttributeName];

[attributes setObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:4] forKey:NSStrokeWidthAttributeName];

[attributes setObject:[UIColor whiteColor] forKey:NSStrokeColorAttributeName];

[text drawInRect:rect withAttributes:attributes];
[attributes removeObjectForKey:NSStrokeWidthAttributeName];
[attributes removeObjectForKey:NSStrokeColorAttributeName];
[attributes setObject:[UIColor blackColor] forKey:NSForegroundColorAttributeName];
[text drawInRect:rect withAttributes:attributes];
UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
return newImage;
```

Comment: You can make it dynamic with a movable label..Take input from user in textfield assign text to label and allow user to move label over imageview any where with UITouch or Gesture

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't really know what problem is, but I did this.. let me know if it works for you

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    UIImage *image    = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image"];
    UIImage *newImage = [self image:image withText:@"Hello World" atPoint:CGPointMake(20, 20)];

    [self saveImage:image    withName:@"original"];
    [self saveImage:newImage withName:@"new"];
}

- (UIImage*)image:(UIImage*)image withText:(NSString*)text atPoint:(CGPoint)point
{
    CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, image.size.width, image.size.height);
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(rect.size, NO, 0);
    [image drawInRect:rect];

    NSDictionary *attributes = @{NSFontAttributeName           : [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:20],
                                 NSStrokeWidthAttributeName    : @(4),
                                 NSStrokeColorAttributeName    : [UIColor whiteColor]};
    [text drawAtPoint:point withAttributes:attributes];

    UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return newImage;
}

- (void)saveImage:(UIImage*)image withName:(NSString*)name
{
    NSString  *documents = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"];
    NSString  *imagePath = [documents stringByAppendingPathComponent:name];

    [UIImagePNGRepresentation(image) writeToFile:imagePath atomically:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
  +(UIImage*) drawText:(NSString*) text 
         inImage:(UIImage*)  image 
         atPoint:(CGPoint)   point 
 {

    UIFont *font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:12];
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(image.size);
    [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,image.size.width,image.size.height)];
    CGRect rect = CGRectMake(point.x, point.y, image.size.width, image.size.height);
    [[UIColor whiteColor] set];
    [text drawInRect:CGRectIntegral(rect) withFont:font]; 
    UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return newImage;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

This answer will make the text both aligned vertically and horizontally in the center of the UIImage.
Note: not my answer it is collected from several answers

```
- (UIImage*)image:(UIImage*)image withText:(NSString*)text{
CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, image.size.width, image.size.height);
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(rect.size, NO, 0);
[image drawInRect:rect];

/// Make a copy of the default paragraph style
NSMutableParagraphStyle *paragraphStyle = [[NSParagraphStyle defaultParagraphStyle] mutableCopy];
/// Set line break mode
paragraphStyle.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByTruncatingTail;
/// Set text horizontal alignment
paragraphStyle.alignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;

NSDictionary *attributes = @{NSFontAttributeName           : [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:16],
                             NSStrokeWidthAttributeName    : @(4),
                             NSStrokeColorAttributeName    : [UIColor whiteColor],
                             NSParagraphStyleAttributeName : paragraphStyle};

CGSize size = [text sizeWithAttributes:attributes];

CGRect newRect = CGRectMake(rect.origin.x,
                      rect.origin.y + (rect.size.height - size.height)/2.0,
                      rect.size.width,
                      size.height);

[text drawInRect:newRect withAttributes:attributes];

UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
return newImage;}
```